# CSS - Placing <divs> over transparent <div>'s

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can make the content/images none-transparent when inside a `<div>` that has a transparency?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="main-button-wrapper" class="left">

        <div id="button-bg-layer" class="box-bg-layer corners"></div>

        <div class="buttons-bg-overlay box-bg-overlay corners">

            <img alt="Test" src="http://www.schroff.co.uk/railway/src/symbol_test.gif" />

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-button-wrapper {
    height: 319px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    position: relative;
    width: 321px;
}

#button-bg-layer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 319px;
    width: 321px;
}

.buttons-bg-overlay {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    margin: 11px;
    height: 66px;
    width: 299px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 26px;
}

#buttons-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 299px;
    height: 297px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 22px;
}

/* Background Layers */

.box-bg-layer {
    background-color: #010101;
    z-index: 1;
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    opacity: 0.4;   
}

.box-bg-overlay {
    background-color: #010101;
    z-index: 2;
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    opacity: 0.4;   
}
```

I've tried putting a `z-index: 4;` on the image. The only other way I can think of is setting the div backgrounds as absolute positioning, then positioning the content outside of the div but there must be an easier way?

Any help would be much appreciated!

See JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sa8jw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a js fiddle for your help :-)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa8jw/3/)

and the changed code . where the opacity is being added to pseudo class after

```
    #main-button-wrapper {
    height: 319px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    position: relative;
    width: 321px;
}

#button-bg-layer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 319px;
    width: 321px;
}

.buttons-bg-overlay {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    margin: 11px;
    height: 66px;
    width: 299px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 26px;
}

#buttons-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 299px;
    height: 297px;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 22px;
}

/* Background Layers */
.box-bg-layer{
background-color: #010101;
    z-index: 1;
zoom: 1;}
.box-bg-layer : after{

    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    opacity: 0.4;   
}
.box-bg-overlay {   background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
    zoom: 1;
}
.box-bg-overlay :after{
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    opacity: 0.4;   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `opacity` use [`rgba`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) where `a` stands for `alpha`. This will make the child elements non transparent...

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); /* RGBA for #010101 will be rgba(1,1,1,.4) */
```

Where `.4` for `a` is equivalent to `opacity: 0.4`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa8jw/2/)

Comment: Yep, opacity is inherited by all children, while an rgba background color won't be.

Comment: @Anobik using any vintage browser? -Ralph Opacity isn't actually inherited :)

Comment: Just checking all browsers now (:

Comment: Let me know if I need to post it as an answer :-)

Comment: @Anobik - works on all browsers, if you could post the answer that would be great :)

Comment: Thanks, Done the same :-) Treat it the way u want :-)